# Bash. Replace with sed. End of line problem

Tags: bash, sed, substitution, end-of-line

I am trying to search and replace in file using sed. But sed seems to hate end of line special char.

```
text=$(shuf text.txt)
echo "This is text:
$text"
sed -i "s~%text%~$text~g" t.txt
```

Here is what I get:

```
This is text:
 line 2
 line 1
 line 3
 line 4
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

I've tried to replace \n with \r but result is not satisfying at all.
There is an option to do **tr '\n' , '$'** and then do it backwards afterwards but it doesn't seems right.

Help?

Comment: In `sed` commands end with a newline. A newline is command delimeter inside `sed`. So `s~blabla\n` is interpreted by sed as a single command. `but it doesn't seems right.` - that is actually a really good idea, I would say go with it. To be extra safe use unreadable character, like `tr '\n' $'\01'`

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to avoid tr?

Comment: A better way is to read the file content when you encounter `%text%`. Also note that `sed` will parse `\r` `\n` and etc. inside `$text` and substitute them, so you may have problems with "\". And sometimes that's also solved with another escaping sed... `sed 's@%text%@$(<<<"$text" sed 's#\\#\\\\#g')/`.... But, as always, [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141387/sed-replace-string-with-file-contents) solution looks neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using sed and bash

Since you are using bash, try:

```
sed -i "s~%text%~${text//$'\n'/\\n}~g" t.txt
```

`${text//$'\n'/\\n}` is an example of bash's *pattern substitution*. 
In this case, it replaces all newline characters with with backslash followed by `n` which `sed` will interpret as a newline.

#### Example

Consider this `text` variable:

```
$ echo "$text"
line 2
 line 1
 line 3
 line 4
```

And this input file:

```
$ cat t.txt
start
%text%
end
```

Now, run our command:

```
$ sed "s~%text%~${text//$'\n'/\\n}~g" t.txt
start
line 2
 line 1
 line 3
 line 4
end
```

To change the file in-place, of course, add the `-i` option back.

## Using awk

With the same `text` variable and `t.txt` file as above:

```
$ awk -v new="$text" '{gsub(/%text%/, new)} 1' t.txt
start
line 2
 line 1
 line 3
 line 4
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Very elegant. :)